# Issue about the scale of y-axis in a bar chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: This image is the dataset that I read into R, and I call it dat3]

I tried to use "ggplot" to create a bar chart to summary this dataset. Here are my codes:

```
ggplot(dat3,aes(variable,value,fill=Industries))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position=
"dodge")+scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

The bar chart look like:
[image]

As we can see, the scale of value looks messy, it doesn't follow the order. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that the `value` column is not numeric. It contains commas which would make it a character variable - but unless you specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you import the data, the values are converted to a factor (as you can see by the `<fctr>` at the top of the column).

The quickest fix is to convert that column to character, remove the commas, then convert to numeric:

```
dat3$value <- as.character(dat3$value)
dat3$value <- gsub(",", "", dat3$value)
dat3$value <- as.numeric(dat3$value)
```

You should also decide whether you want `Industries` and `variable` to be factors.